# Matching as an induced subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a bipartite graph. Say $V'$ induces a $k$-matching if $G[V']$
has $2k$ vertices and $k$ edges such that every connected component contains two vertices.
Does a graph $G$ wich contains an induced
$k$-matching have a special name?

I am looking for any known necessary/sufficient conditions for such a graph.

Comment: What I can tell you is that finding the maximum $k$ such that $G$ has a $k$-matching is NP-Hard, even in bipartite graphs.  So there might not be nice characterizations.  See http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X05002633

Comment: Thank you @ManuelLafond ! The link also mentioned that induced matching is hard even on a bipartite graph, which was useful to me.